# GetText() memoryleak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, wchar, widechar

This is my first post so be gentle :D

I just started at this job and my first task was to find the leak which I did, pointed out by the comment.
I control clicked gettext() and I get

```
virtual System::WideChar * __fastcall GetText(void);
```

I added 5 extra pwide and the leak increased (memory usage in task master increased by 1000).

I tried delete and free but i get exceptions. Anyone got any advice on how to plug the leak?

Here is my code:

```
UnicodeString CReportManager::GetFinalHTML()
{
UnicodeString ret = "";
ret = "<Reports>";

if( ErrorHTML->Count )
{
    ret += "<Errors>" + UnicodeString(ErrorHTML->GetText()) + "</Errors>";
}

//System::WideChar *pWide= ReportHTML->GetText();
//System::WideChar *pWide4= ReportHTML->GetText();
//System::WideChar *pWide1= ReportHTML->GetText();
//System::WideChar *pWide2= ReportHTML->GetText();
//System::WideChar *pWide3= ReportHTML->GetText();
    //delete pWide;
   //   free(pWide);
    //ret +=pWide;
ret += ReportHTML->GetText();          //leak here
ret += "</Reports>";

#ifdef _DEBUG
ReportHTML->SaveToFile("C:\\debug.xml");
#endif

delete ReportHTML;
delete ErrorHTML;

ReportHTML = NULL;
ErrorHTML = NULL;


return ret;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `GetText()`?

Comment: Welcome. First of all, it is unclear, what framework or library do you use here, RadStudio? Do you get exceptions on both `free` and `delete`?

Comment: Do you have permission to post company code on the internet?

Comment: Does `GetText` return a heap allocated value?

Comment: How does `UnicodeString` attach a new part with `+=`, does it copy value, or just stores memory location? Did you get an exception trying to do `ret += pWide` after freeing `pWide`?

Comment: Hey guys, ty for the quick response. i posted the solution below.
to answer som question, yes both free and delete  generated execption
sry i dont know what GetText returns(i think its a long string because its suppose to be a string)
i dont see the point on posting the GetText() since i have the solution.
if you do have similar problem and the StrDispose() doesnt work ill post GetText(). again thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, if anyone has the same problem, the solution is `StrDispose(pWide);`
I tried it with all 4 extra `pWide` and my memory leak was gone :

```
UnicodeString CReportManager::GetFinalHTML()
{
    UnicodeString ret = "";
    ret = "<Reports>";

    if( ErrorHTML->Count )
    {
        ret += "<Errors>" + UnicodeString(ErrorHTML->GetText()) + "</Errors>";
    }

    System::WideChar *pWide= ReportHTML->GetText();

    //delete pWide;
    //free(pWide);
    ret +=pWide;
    StrDispose(pWide);

    //ret += ReportHTML->GetText();          //leak here
    ret += "</Reports>";

#ifdef _DEBUG
    ReportHTML->SaveToFile("C:\\debug.xml");
#endif

    delete ReportHTML;
    delete ErrorHTML;

    ReportHTML = NULL;
    ErrorHTML = NULL;

    return ret;
}
```